# How can the condition be reduced to one line?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I set the condition like this:

```
<mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip color="accent" *ngIf="letter.status == 'Completed'" selected>
        {{ letter.status }}
    </mat-chip>
    <mat-chip color="warn" *ngIf="letter.status == 'In Work'" selected>
        {{letter.status }}
    </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Is it possible to reduced it down so it looks something like this:

```
<mat-chip color="letter.status == 'Completed' ? accent : warn" selected>
    {{ letter.status }}
</mat-chip>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Input() color: ThemePalette Theme color palette for the component.`

color is an input property

`color="accent"` static 
`[color]="expr ? 'accent' : 'warn'"` dynamic

```
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip
    [color]="letter.status == 'Completed' ? 'accent' : 'warn'"
    selected
    selected
  >
    {{ letter.status }}
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/d9lezg--run?file=src/app/chips-drag-drop-example.html)